# Can you make a method of an inner class only accessible by the outer class?

Tags: java

Lets say I have an outer class and an inner class. Is it possible to write an inner class method, such that it is only accessible by the outer class and not by classes defined outside of the outer class, e.g. `MyForeignClass`?

```
class MyForeignClass {
    MyForeignClass() {
        MyOuterClass instance = new MyOuterClass();
        MyInnerClass innerClassInstance = instance.getMyInnerClassInstance();
        // illegal method call, only MyOuterClass can call this
        innerClassInstance.privateInnerClassMethod();
    }
}

class MyOuterClass {
    class MyInnerClass {
        MyInnerClass() {}
        void publicInnerClassMethod() {
            // accessible from outside MyOuterClass
        }
        void privateInnerClassMethod() {
            // accessible from inside MyOuterClass
        }
    }

    MyInnerClass instance;

    MyOuterClass() {
        instance = new MyInnerClass();
        instance.privateInnerClassMethod();
    } 

    MyInnerClass getMyInnerClassInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make it... private?

Comment: Declare the inner class a private class.

Comment: @GlenPierce no, because `publicInnerClassMethod` should be "accessible from outside MyOuterClass". Making the class `private` precludes that.

Comment: Andy, you need to answer more often ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make the methods of the inner class private they will only be able to be accessed from the inner and outer class.

```
class MyOuterClass
{
    class MyInnerClass 
    {
        private void doSomething(){}
    }
}
```

If you tried to call the above method from any other class but MyInnerClass or MyOuterClass you would get an error because no other class would know where that instance of the method came from.Hope this helps :)

Comment: True indeed, I will add that as part of my answer

Comment: Done *thumbs up*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Aaron :)

Comment: This does not seem the case with Kotlin. Outer class is not able to access the private functions of the inner class. Does anyone know an alternative way for Kotlin?